# Installing Openrave Package

Tags: ros, rosmake, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install [openrave package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openrave_planning) for ros-electric on my Ubuntu 10.04.

```
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/openrave_planning
```

I tried to rosmake the package but it turned out there's some error. So I then downloaded the following packages

posedetection_msgs

```
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/jsk_common/posedetection_msgs
```

parallel_util

```
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/jsk_common/parallel_util
```

I rosmake those packages and re-rosmake the openrave_planning package.
However, new error occurred

```
  [rospack] couldn't find package [soqt]
  echo "prefix=/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet\n\
  libdir=/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet/build/include\n\
  includedir=/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet/lib\n\
  \n\
  Name: Bullet\n\
  Description: Bullet as built by ROS\n\
  Version: 2.74\n\
  Libs: -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet/lib -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lLinearMath        \n\
  CFlags: -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bullet/include -DBT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION -DBT_EULER_DEFAULT_ZYX      " > bullet.pc
  cd `rospack find openrave` && rm -rf share/openrave include/rave include/openrave-core.h share/openrave0.3/openravepy && rm -f build/CMakeCache.txt && export PATH="/bin:/home/bcddivad/code/ros/openrave/openrave_planning/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/bcddivad/code/ros/openrave/openrave_planning/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix:/home/bcddivad/code/ros/openrave/openrave_planning/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games" && export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=":`rospack find openrave`" && mkdir -p build && cd build && BOOST_INCLUDEDIR= BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`rospack find openrave` -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DODE_USE_MULTITHREAD=ON -D_odeconfig_cflags:STRING="-I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/physics_ode/opende/opende/include -DdDOUBLE -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/physics_ode/opende/threadpool  " -D_odeconfig_lflags:STRING="-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/physics_ode/opende/opende/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/physics_ode/opende/opende/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/physics_ode/opende/opende/lib -lode  " ../openrave_svn && export PARALLEL_JOBS=ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS && make -l8
  CMake Error: The source directory "/home/bcddivad/code/ros/openravecode/openrave/openrave_svn" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32866/installing-openrave-package/) by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably should install libsoqt4-dev, go to synaptic and try to install this package!

---

Originally posted by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0